# how to set android ImageView visibility inside an included layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

We are using android API 17 in our application. I have defined a layout containing two images vies as below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image_container_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image_1_resource"/>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_2"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_container_layout"
        android:src="@drawable/image_2_resource"/>
```

This layout is included inside another layout as below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    style="@style/wizard_content_style"
    tools:context=".ui.Wizard"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    >


<include layout="@layout/image_container_layout"
         android:id="@+id/included_view"
            />

<TextView
        style="@style/wizard_content_text_style_medium"
        android:id="@+id/text_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/included_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/instruction"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>
```

The reason that the layout is included is that we want to reuse it in two more layouts.
Now based on some condition I want to hide or show the image views inside `image_container_layout`.

The java code looks like this:

```
  containerLayout = (ViewGroup) ((Activity) getAndroidContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_container_layout, null);
   image1 = (ImageView) containerLayout.findViewById(R.id.image_1);
   image2 = (ImageView) containerLayout.findViewById(R.id.image_2);
  switch (accuracy) {
    case 1:
        log().i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "case 1 chosen");
        image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        log().i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "image 1 has been shown");
        break;
    case 2:
        image1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        image2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case 3:
        image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
}
```

I am debugging this code and I am sure the code is running. The log messages are printed in Logcat as well, but nothing happens no change in the images. Also, both images are always shown. 
I wonder if there is something that I have to do when working with the included layout? 
Thanks for any help in advance. 
Based on answers I got below, seems that inflating a view will create a new object and because of this,  changes in the visibility are not shown on the user interface.
Then the question is that if we have a wizard and inside 3 different pages of the wizard I want to have an image and depending on some condition I want to show or hide the image, what is the best solution? I mean I want to reuse the code which is responsible for hiding and showing the image regardless which page of wizard is active.

Comment: You didn't set the width and height of your included layout, try doing so.

Comment: I don't think inflating the layout is necessary as you already have access to it. Try commenting out that block.

Comment: @GiddyNaya I removed inflating the layout. Then I am getting NullPointeException when calling setVisibility. Meaning that it can not find ImageView.

Comment: @Govan It would be great if you post the complete java class instead of the above code block so we can get the full picture of your implementation. Because you can only get a NullPointerException in this case when you aren't referencing the actual layout containing the ImageViews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you complexing with so much code. If you include some layout in your xml then you can use those widgets also same as the xml have. There is no need to inflate.

```
ImageView image_2 = findViewById(R.id.image_2);
image_2.setVisbility(Visible.GONE);
```

Comment: The code is not inside activity class. It means that I don't have access to findViewByID. Without inflating view I am getting npe. It means it can not find ImageView. Beside this the code is running and it finds an ImageView. The problem is that the setVisibility is not taking affect.

Comment: can you tell me in detail, where  you exactly want to acess so i can give you proper answer

Comment: Do you mean that every time I am inflating a view I am getting a new view object and because of this I am not seeing changes in visibility. In that case What should I use instead of include? I want to have the same image view in 3 different layouts or pages in wizard when I am changing the visibility then I want to all 3 has the same visibility.

Answer (score 1):

You said at this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57217204/how-to-set-android-imageview-visibility-inside-an-included-layout#comment100942112_57217371) the code not inside activity but wherever it is you inflated a new layout to your view currently displaying by this line:
`containerLayout = (ViewGroup) ((Activity) getAndroidContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_container_layout, null);`

When you try to change visibility of those images actually it works, i think so. But if your activity or fragment layout contains `image_container_layout` maybe you see 
those images.

And I wonder that what do you do with inflated view `containerLayout`. Do you add it to inside of any other view. If you dont it wont be visible for you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use it like this:

```
View included_view1 = findViewById(R.id.included_view1);
ImageView image_1 = included_view1.findViewById(R.id.image_1);
ImageView image_2 = included_view1.findViewById(R.id.image_2);
image_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
image_1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
image_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
image_2.setVisibility(View.GONE)

View included_view2 = findViewById(R.id.included_view2);
ImageView image_11 = included_view2.findViewById(R.id.image_1);
ImageView image_22 = included_view2.findViewById(R.id.image_2);
image_11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
image_11.setVisibility(View.GONE);
image_22.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
image_22.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Above code will be helpful in the case of multiple time you want to use same layout.